# Use CSS hover to increase underline and color, but no effect

Tags: html, css, hover

HTML code:

```
<a href="#">Google</a><br/>
```

CSS code:

```
a:link{color: black;text-decoration:none;}
a.hover{textdecoration: underline;}
a.visited {color: red;}
```

I try to none of underline and when I hover to this link, it will be show us underline, and font also become red, but it was failed.

Comment: you are using a dot(.) instead of a colon(:) for your pseudo classes....https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp

Comment: Also, the property is `text-decoration` and not *textdecoration*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the main issue is that you're using `a.hover {}` instead of `a:hover{}` ... you have it right with `a:link{}`.

Try this:

```
a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

a:visited {
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `a:hover` and `a:visited` insted of `a.hover` and `a.visited`.

For exemple:

```
a:hover{textdecoration: underline;}
a:visited {color: red;}
```